# Did I implement the increment operator for my dynamic bit set correctly because it is giving unexpected output

Tags: c++, bitset

I have my a overloaded increment operator function for my DynamicBitset class.

```
DynamicBitset DynamicBitset::operator++(int)
{

int byteCount = 0;
unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int lastCharBitIndex;

while ((this->array[byteCount] << count & 1) != 0)
{
    if ((int)(count / 8) >= this->arrayLength)
    {
        this->zeroOutArray();
        this->addByte(1);
        return *this;
    }
    if (count % 8 == 0)
    {
        byteCount = count / 8;
    }
    count++;
}

lastCharBitIndex = count - (byteCount * 8);

if (count % 8 != 0)
{
    zeroUpTo(count);
    this->array[byteCount] = this->array[byteCount] + (unsigned char)(pow(2, lastCharBitIndex - 1));
}
else
{
    zeroUpTo(count);
    this->array[byteCount] += 1;
}

std::cout << "This Ran!";

return *this;
}
```

Here are the private variable declarations.

```
unsigned char* array;
unsigned int arrayLength;
unsigned int bitLength;
```

But when I add a byte like 97 or 'a' on the ascii table and try to increment it, it gives me  the value 221 when it should be 98.

Comment: Using `pow` for an integer calculation is a bad idea. Use a shift instead since it's a power of two. A [mcve] demonstrating the issue you're having would help.

Comment: If you haven't done it before, now is the time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: And as a general tip for making testing and debugging easier: Don't write large bits of code all at one. Instead add just a very small piece of code, perhaps just one or two lines. Then build with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors. Only when the code builds cleanly continue to testing. If you have a problem, it's much easier to isolate the code causing the problem, to debug it, find the problem, and fix it.

Comment: Which resource did you learn that you need to use `this->` syntax?  You only need to use it to differentiate between parameter names and member names.  You can eliminate the `this->` syntax by using a coding style where parameter names are different than member names.  A common style is to prefix member names with "m_".

Comment: Use bitshift operator '<< 1' instead of `std::pow` when working with bits or you will run into rounding issues at some point. And since you return `*this` you should return a reference to the bitset  `DynamicBitset&`

Comment: I learned it when watching a video on the 'this' keyword and from my computer science teacher. And I thought it would be a nice way to always know what is a member variable and whats not.

Comment: Don't learn C++ from watching videos most of them are honestly crap

Comment: How Should I learn c++? My teacher helps me once in a blue moon because he has other classes to teach and our class is over java. I tried getting a course on udemy but it was covering all the basics all over again.

Comment: To learn C++ you can start here: https://www.learncpp.com/ (not perfect but quite good and up-to-date). Then refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup what C++ has to offer.
And finally read the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up-to-date with how C++ should be used, it always has the latest guidelines.

Comment: Also it is fine to keep asking questions on code you've written here if you have one specific question on that code (otherwise there is stackoverflow's codereview site too).
Also to give you an idea, C++ already has a class for what you are trying to do : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: My teacher told me when I first learning I should build everything from scratch. Although I am willing to try a different way. I adapt very quickly to new coding practices so if theres a place I can find good coding practices I would like to know.

Comment: Well your teacher is right. Not because you cannot adapt quickly to writing code in another language but becuase C++ works very differently than java (or python or C#).  For example the lifetime of objects in C++ is determined by scopes ('{' ... '}') and not by a garbage collector. So it is never a good idea to convert code in one language line by line to another language. Understand the algorithm and rewrite it with the behavior of the new language in mind. So yes be prepared to put time into understanding how the new language differs from your current one..

Comment: But the main question is, why on God's green earth does a bitset need the increment operator?

Comment: Please share the other parts of your class and also the code how you call the test mentioned in your last paragraph.

Comment: I am relatively new to programming but not completely new. So I do know basic syntax for a lot of languages but I have devoted most of my time to c++. The increment is for my binary commpression to make a unique bit key. And if you want to view the entire project the github is https://github.com/ChristianDoesCode/DynamicBitset.git

Comment: You probably need is a number, not a bitset.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the return type was one of the problems. And also my original algorithm just wasn't correct which makes sense because I was tired when I wrote it. So I just rewrote it today and it works.

```
void DynamicBitset::operator++(int)
{
unsigned int byteCount = 0;
unsigned int bitIndex = 0;

while ((this->array[byteCount] >> bitIndex & 1) != 0)
{
    if ((unsigned int)(bitIndex / 8) > this->arrayLength)
    {
        this->zeroOutArray();
        this->addByte(1);
        return;
    }
    if (bitIndex % 8 == 0)
    {
        byteCount = bitIndex / 8;
    }
    bitIndex++;
}

unsigned int subArrayLength = (unsigned int)(bitIndex / 8);
unsigned int lastCharBitIndex = bitIndex - (subArrayLength * 8);
unsigned char powerMask = 1;

this->zeroUpTo(bitIndex);

this->array[subArrayLength] += (powerMask << lastCharBitIndex);
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement some of the suggestions from the previous comments like using bitshift instead of math pow function.

Comment: `++` is usually expected to have a return value.

Comment: I know but when I put a return value it gives me undefined behavior which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Could you use the pre-increment instead? It typically returns a reference, which is more performant for complicated objects. Your UB could come from possible problems in your copy constructor, which is called, when returning by value in your post-increment function.

Comment: Do you know the rules of 0, 3, 5, btw?

Comment: No I havent learned those rulues what are they?

Comment: Those are rules of thumb and they say: If you need a user-defined destructor, then you should also create a user-defined (or delete them) copy constructor and copy assignment operator. And for higher performance also the move versions. Otherwise you may e.g. copy a pointer instead of allocating new memory and copy the contents. In the first case at destruction time you would free the same pointer twice. To make this simpler, one usually does not use `new` and `delete`, but `std::unique_ptr` for member variables. Then no user-defined destructor is needed for dynamic memory. All is automatic.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion I will look into implementing it.